# Get class instance of ReactElement

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am trying to get the instance of a ReactElement Component.

I have the following (example) code:

```tsx
import { Component, ReactElement } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Foo extends Component {
    public myAwesomeString = "meow";

    public myAwesomeFunction(echo: string) {
        console.log(echo);
    }

    public render() {
        return <span>Some content</span>;
    }
}

class Bar extends Component<{ children: ReactElement }> {
    public componentDidMount() {
        // this.props.children.myAwesomeFunction("meow") <-- How would I do this?
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <>
                {this.props.children}
                <span>{/* this.props.children.myAwesomeString */}</span> {/* <-- And this?*/}
            </>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Bar>
        <Foo />
    </Bar>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Is there any way to get the instance `Foo` from `Bar` when `Foo` is a child of `Bar`?
I have tried using `this.props.children.ref` but I just got `null`...
Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean that from within the `Foo` component you want to be able to tell if it's parent is `Bar`?

Comment: No, exactly the opposite, from `Bar` get the `Foo` instance

Comment: You can't, and shouldn't! Try to find another way to solve your problem! What do you really want to do?

Comment: Yeah, that seems really odd. Maybe explain what you are trying to accomplish and why, and we can make recommendations.

Comment: I am trying to do something similar to [this](https://medium.com/@srph/react-imitating-vue-slots-eab8393f96fd), but the *slot* needs to get the child instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Context`'s to register the child component:

```tsx
import { Component, ReactElement, createContext, ContextType } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const RegisterContext = createContext({ register: (cp: Foo) => {} });

class Foo extends Component {
    public static contextType = RegisterContext;
    declare context: ContextType<typeof RegisterContext>;

    public componentDidMount() {
        this.context.register(this); // <--
    }

    public myAwesomeString = "meow";

    public myAwesomeFunction(echo: string) {
        console.log(echo);
    }

    public render() {
        return <span>Some content</span>;
    }
}

class Bar extends Component<{ children: ReactElement }> {
    private foo!: Foo;

    public componentDidMount() {
        this.foo.myAwesomeFunction("meow");
    }

    public registerFoo(foo: Foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public render() {
        return (
            <>
                <RegisterContext.Provider
                    value={{ register: this.registerFoo }}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </RegisterContext.Provider>
                <span>{this.foo.myAwesomeString}</span>
            </>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Bar>
        <Foo />
    </Bar>,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I haven't tested this specific example out yet, but it looks as if it would work.